# Quirks mode table and text alignment issues

Tags: html, css, quirks-mode

I have the following html code snippet :-

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body ul
        {
            margin: 0px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 0px;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        ul li {
        display: inline;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        table
        {
            display: inline;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            border:1px solid green;

        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
        <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
        <li>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Item3</td>
                        <td>Stars</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </li>
    </ul>

</body>
    </html>
```

I have to render this code in **quirks mode**(Due to an Iframe in the page, to render it properly I found that Quirks mode suits the best). I see that IE8 displays the code as: 
[image]
<sub>(source: [ggpht.com](https://lh6.ggpht.com/_jUmpazWfMB4/S4NZgY3JM9I/AAAAAAAABnM/clSvTHPjWaE/s800/IE8.png.jpg))</sub>

Table not aligned with the other list items.
Whereas mozilla displays it as :-

[image]
<sub>(source: [ggpht.com](https://lh5.ggpht.com/_jUmpazWfMB4/S4NZfoO3gNI/AAAAAAAABnI/PsxHjokD1Pg/s800/moz.png.jpg))</sub>

Here the table is aligned but the text is not.

What is going wrong here? How do I fix this across browsers

Comment: Sometimes, setting a value to its default makes IE magically work.  Perhaps you could mess with valign?  Thats what I tend to try first, when I have to work with... *slants eyes* that browser.  This is especially important for tables, where IE seems to only work for me if i say "valign:bottom" for every single tag in the table...

Comment: No.. not working here. The problem is elsewhere :(

Answer (score 0):

Insist on quirks mode? OK.

It looks like the td within the table has padding that causes it to render like that in IE.

Try removing padding+margin on all elements after table.

Comment: Nope.. 0 padding for all.. still the same.. If u see the image, ull see that the table altogether is positioned a little higher in IE